# Mocking class selectors with OCMock

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I'm trying to test a class that implements two class methods from `NSURLConnection`, but keep getting the error:

```
error: testSyncConnection (MyURLConnectionTest) failed: *** -[NSProxy doesNotRecognizeSelector:sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] called!
```

Here's the interface for `MyURLConnection`:

```
@interface MyURLConnection : NSURLConnection

+ (void) sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue*) queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*)) handler;
+ (NSData *) sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse (NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error;

@end
```

Here's how i'm trying to Mock it:

```
- (void)testSyncConnection
{

    id testConnection = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[MyURLConnection class]];

    [[[testConnection stub] andReturn:Nil] sendSynchronousRequest:Nil
                                                returningResponse:Nil
                                                            error:Nil];

    //rest of test...

}
```

which fails at the stubbing part, producing the error I posted above..

I also made sure the `MyDURLConnection` implementation is added to the Test target too.

Any tips what I'm missing here ?

Comment: have you tried `[[[[testConnection stub] classMethod] andReturn:nil] sendSynchronousRequest:...` ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the docs explain that this is to be done only when you have a class and instance method with the exact same name, which is not my case unfortunately..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of OCMock are you using? Mocking class methods is supported since 2.1.

Apart from that, this works for me:

```
id testConnection = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[MyURLConnection class]];

[[[testConnection stub] andReturn:nil] sendSynchronousRequest:nil
                                            returningResponse:nil
                                                        error:NULL];

STAssertNil([MyURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:nil returningResponse:nil error:NULL], nil);
```

Comment: One internets for you good sir !
For some reason I assumed I had the latest version, downloaded 2.2.1 now and it works perfectly :)